# How to authorize google api access for installed applications (not using localhost)

Tags: python, api, authorization

I have a standalone application written in Python that is using the Native Google Client API for generating queries against my schema in BigQuery.  The code attempts to authorize the google api as you would expect.  My client secrets that is referenced from the python apps specifies a redirect option of "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".  When I run the application it renders the google authorization page in my default browser as expected.  When I press Accept, I get a No Response from Server error.  I noticed the URL in the address bar starts with, http://localhost:8080, which indicates the response is expecting that I have a local webserver running that is listening on port 8080, which I don't.  I'm not sure why its trying to redirect to localhost instead of the option I specified in my client secrets json file.

I suspect this is the reason I am unable to authorize, but not sure why its redirecting to Localhost.

Thanks,
J.D.

Comment: The issue is not that the localhost URL is being rendered, but the fact that I get an error response from server.  The page says, ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was environmental in nature.  My machine (MacBook) wasn't recognizing localhost, so if I modify the URL to be 127.0.0.1, then the authorization completes normally.

J.D.